How to fix error "Failed to start: Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0"
I'm a beginner Ubuntu user, using version 20.04. Ubuntu randomly black-screened on me today when I wasn't doing much, I just had Firefox and Discord open. I held the power button on my laptop down to restart, but after trying to boot up again my screen just stays black, with the exception of a frozen insert character cursor in the top left corner of the screen.
Here is a screenshot of a video I took of the errors during the boot up process (apologies for the image quality, but the text goes by very quickly when it's booting)
Error 1: Failed to Start Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes and Error 2: Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0:

For background context, I had the same issues with the graphics drivers when I first installed Ubuntu, but I never quite "resolved" these issues, instead on boot in GRUB I select advanced options and select "Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-89-generic" and these issues did not manifest on this kernel version, until now.
I tried using recovery mode, by updating grub, and checking files, and I can successfully boot in recovery mode with disabled graphics drivers; obviously this is not ideal, but nothing else seems to work.
My system specs are as follows:

Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot setup with Windows 10
GRUB version 2.06
Machine: ROG Strix Laptop with AMD Ryzen 5900HX with integrated graphics and Nvidia RTX 3060

I would prefer to be able to run Ubuntu using solely the AMD integrated graphics as I don't need the discrete GPU at all when running Ubuntu, which greatly extends my battery life.

I had a similar problem, and it went away updating
/etc/default/grub
with:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
update-grub and reboot

It didn't work for me.

@SalahAdDin: try something like acpi_backlight=video/native/None
